# How to see that this is a mixture of the uniform and Erlang?

Tags: density-function, uniform-distribution

I have a pdf in a form:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\lambda^k x^{k-1} e^{-\lambda x}}{k!} & \text{for $0<x<1$} \\ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\lambda^k x^{k-1} e^{-\lambda x}}{k!} & \text{for $x \ge 1$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I can see that this is a mixture of $\text{Erlang}(k,\lambda)$ with probability $0.5$ and some other distribution. Believe it might be uniform $U(0,1)$ but I cannot see how it would work.

Comment: It is indeed half Erlang/gamma and half Uniform on $(0,1)$,  The pdf is fairly clearly the average of the pdfs of the two original distributions: the $\frac12 +$ part for $0 < x < 1$ is half of $1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Your density function for the Erlang distribution is wrong, so I will correct that in my answer.  (What you give is not a valid density function since it does not integrate to one.)  My answer assumes this correction is made.*

Yes, this is a mixture of an Erlang random variable and a uniform random variable (with equal probability).  Specifically, if you let $X_0 \sim \text{U}(0,1)$ and $X_1 \sim \text{Erlang}(k,\lambda)$ then your random variable is the mixture:

$$X = X_Y \quad \quad \quad Y \sim \text{Bern}(\tfrac{1}{2}).$$

To see this, apply the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to get:

$$\begin{align}
p(X=x) 
&= p(Y=0) \cdot p(X=x|Y=0) + p(Y=1) \cdot p(X=x|Y=1) \\[6pt]
&= \tfrac{1}{2} \cdot p(X_0=x) + \tfrac{1}{2} \cdot p(X_1=x) \\[6pt]
&= \tfrac{1}{2} \cdot \text{U}(x|0,1) + \tfrac{1}{2} \cdot \text{Erlang}(x|k,\lambda) \\[12pt]
&= \begin{cases}
\ 0 & & & \text{for } x \leqslant 0, \\[10pt]
\tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k x^{k-1} e^{-\lambda x}}{(k-1)!} & & & \text{for } 0 < x < 1, \\[6pt]
\tfrac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k x^{k-1} e^{-\lambda x}}{(k-1)!} & & & \text{for } x \geqslant 1, \\[6pt]
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$